# Create directx9 normal map texture

Tags: c++, mapping, directx

I want to create a normal map texture for my terrain mesh i am generating with my cpu, I am not asking you to write my code for me. I am asking you to send me to a tutorial that is independent, because every tutorial i get already has a backwards series, and i don't want to go back... Please help me. Or give me steps on what i should do...

My Terrain.h

```
#ifndef TERRAIN_H
#define TERRAIN_H
#endif

#include "d3dUtil.h"
#include <string>
const int NUM_VERTS = 528;
const int NUM_INDICES = 792;

class Terrain{
public:
    //Constructor
    Terrain(int x, int y, int z, std::wstring fileName, char* heightmap);
    Terrain(int x, int y, int z, std::wstring fileName, float terrainData[64][64][4]);
    //Destructor
    ~Terrain();
    //Methods
    void Initialize(IDirect3DDevice9* device);
    void Update(float dt);
    void Draw(IDirect3DDevice9* device);
    void Release();
    void raiseVertex(int X, int Z, IDirect3DDevice9* device);
    //Publc attributes
    int m_iXPos;
    int m_iYPos;
    int m_iZPos;
    std::wstring texName;
    float m_faTerrainData[64][64][4];

private:
    //Attributes
    int m_iWidth;
    int m_iHeight;
    int m_iVertexCount;
    int m_iIndeciseCount;
    D3DXMATRIX world;
    IDirect3DVertexBuffer9* vBuffer;
    IDirect3DIndexBuffer9*  iBuffer;
    IDirect3DTexture9* texture;
    D3DXMATRIX GetWorld();
    D3DMATERIAL9 material;

};
```

My Terrain.cpp

```
#include "Terrain.h"
#include <math.h>

static const int NUMV;

Terrain::Terrain(int x, int y, int z, std::wstring fileName, float terrainData[64][64][4]){
    float test[64][64][4];
    float val = 10;
    for(int X = 0; X < 64; X ++){
        for(int Y = 0; Y < 64; Y ++){
            for(int Z = 0; Z < 4; Z ++){
                val = terrainData[X][Y][Z];
                m_faTerrainData[X][Y][Z] = val;
            }
        }
    }
    m_iXPos = x;
    m_iYPos = y;
    m_iZPos = z;
    m_iVertexCount =  16384;
    m_iIndeciseCount = 24576;
    texName = fileName;
    material.Ambient = (D3DXCOLOR)d3dColors::WHITE;
    material.Diffuse = (D3DXCOLOR)d3dColors::WHITE;
    material.Emissive = (D3DXCOLOR)d3dColors::BLACK;
    material.Power = 5.0f;
    material.Specular = (D3DXCOLOR)d3dColors::WHITE;
}

Terrain::Terrain(int x, int y, int z, std::wstring fileName, char* heightmap){
    m_iXPos = x;
    m_iYPos = y;
    m_iZPos = z;
    m_iVertexCount =  16384;
    m_iIndeciseCount = 24576;
    BYTE R = 0;
    BYTE G = 0;
    BYTE B = 0;
    texName = fileName;
    material.Ambient = (D3DXCOLOR)d3dColors::WHITE;
    material.Diffuse = (D3DXCOLOR)d3dColors::WHITE;
    material.Emissive = (D3DXCOLOR)d3dColors::BLACK;
    material.Power = 5.0f;
    material.Specular = (D3DXCOLOR)d3dColors::WHITE;
}

Terrain::~Terrain(){

}


void Terrain::Initialize(IDirect3DDevice9* device){
    D3DVertex::VertexPositionNormalTexture verts[16384];
    WORD indices[24576];
    float j = sqrt((float)(m_iVertexCount / 4));
    float n = 0;    
    float g = 0;
    float X = 32;
    float Z = 32;
    float textRep = 1.0f;
    float textRepo = 0.0f;
int iVertex = 0;
int iIndex = 0;
for(int x = 0; x < j; x ++){
    for(int z = 0; z < j; z ++){
        if(iVertex < m_iVertexCount){
            verts[iVertex] = D3DVertex::VertexPositionNormalTexture(x, m_faTerrainData[(int)x][(int)z][0], z+1, n, 1.0f, g, textRepo, textRepo);
            verts[iVertex+1] = D3DVertex::VertexPositionNormalTexture(x+1,  m_faTerrainData[(int)x][(int)z][1], z+1, n, 1.0f, g, textRep, textRepo);
            verts[iVertex+2] = D3DVertex::VertexPositionNormalTexture(x,  m_faTerrainData[(int)x][(int)z][2], z, n, 1.0f, g, textRepo, textRep);
            verts[iVertex+3] = D3DVertex::VertexPositionNormalTexture(x+1,  m_faTerrainData[(int)x][(int)z][3], z, n, 1.0f, g, textRep, textRep);
            textRep += 0.5f;
            textRepo += 0.5f;
            if(textRep > 1){
                textRep = 1;
                    textRepo = 0;
            }
        indices[iIndex  ] = iVertex;
        indices[iIndex+1] = iVertex+1;
        indices[iIndex+2] = iVertex+2;
        indices[iIndex+3] = iVertex+2;
        indices[iIndex+4] = iVertex+1;
        indices[iIndex+5] = iVertex+3;

        iVertex += 4;
        iIndex += 6;
        }
    }
}
    device->CreateVertexBuffer(m_iVertexCount * sizeof(D3DVertex::VertexPositionNormalTexture),
        NULL,
        D3DVertex::VertexPositionNormalTexture::FVF,
        D3DPOOL_MANAGED,
        &vBuffer,
        NULL);

    VOID* pVerts;
    vBuffer->Lock(0, sizeof(verts), (void**)&pVerts, 0);
    memcpy_s(pVerts, sizeof(verts), verts, sizeof(verts));
    vBuffer->Unlock();
    device->CreateIndexBuffer(m_iIndeciseCount * sizeof(WORD), D3DUSAGE_WRITEONLY,
        D3DFMT_INDEX16,
        D3DPOOL_MANAGED,
        &iBuffer,
        NULL);

    VOID* pIndices;
    iBuffer->Lock(0, sizeof(indices), (void**)&pIndices, 0);
    memcpy_s(pIndices, sizeof(indices), indices, sizeof(indices));
    iBuffer->Unlock();

    //Load texture
    D3DXCreateTextureFromFile(device, texName.c_str(), &texture);
    if(!texture){
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Could not load texture", NULL, NULL);
        return;
    }
}

void Terrain::Update(float dt){
    //  rotation.y += dt;
    //rotation.x += dt;
    //rotation.z += dt;
}

void Terrain::Draw(IDirect3DDevice9* device){
    device->SetTexture(0, texture);
    device->SetMaterial(&material);
    device->SetTransform(D3DTS_WORLD, &GetWorld());
    device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_NORMALIZENORMALS, true);
    device->SetStreamSource(0, vBuffer, 0, sizeof(D3DVertex::VertexPositionNormalTexture));
    device->SetIndices(iBuffer);
    device->SetFVF(D3DVertex::VertexPositionNormalTexture::FVF);
    device->DrawIndexedPrimitive(D3DPT_TRIANGLELIST, 0, 0, m_iIndeciseCount, 0, m_iIndeciseCount/3);
}

D3DXMATRIX Terrain::GetWorld(){
    D3DXMATRIX _scale, rX, rY, rZ, tRanslate;
    D3DXVECTOR3 scale = D3DXVECTOR3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    D3DXVECTOR3 rotation = D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    D3DXVECTOR3 position = D3DXVECTOR3(m_iXPos, m_iYPos, m_iZPos);
    D3DXMatrixScaling(&_scale, scale.x, scale.y, scale.z);
    D3DXMatrixRotationX(&rX, rotation.x);
    D3DXMatrixRotationY(&rY, rotation.y);
    D3DXMatrixRotationZ(&rZ, rotation.z);
    D3DXMatrixTranslation(&tRanslate, position.x, position.y, position.z);
    world = _scale * rX * rY* rZ* tRanslate;
    return world;
}

void Terrain::Release(){
    delete(iBuffer);
    delete(vBuffer);
    delete(texture);
    iBuffer = 0;
    vBuffer = 0;
    texture = 0;
}

void Terrain::raiseVertex(int X, int Z, IDirect3DDevice9* device){
    iBuffer = 0;
    vBuffer = 0;
    texture = 0;
    D3DVertex::VertexPositionNormalTexture verts[16384];
    WORD indices[24576];
    float j = sqrt((float)(m_iVertexCount / 4));
    float n = 0;    
    float g = 0;

int iVertex = 0;
int iIndex = 0;
for(int x = 0; x < j; x ++){
    for(int z = 0; z < j; z ++){
        if(iVertex < m_iVertexCount){
            if(x == X)
                if(z == Z){
            verts[iVertex] = D3DVertex::VertexPositionNormalTexture(x, 0.0f, z+1, n, 1.0f, g, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            verts[iVertex+1] = D3DVertex::VertexPositionNormalTexture(x+1, 0.5f, z+1, n, 1.0f, g, 1.0f, 0.0f);
            verts[iVertex+2] = D3DVertex::VertexPositionNormalTexture(x, 0.0f, z, n, 1.0f, g, 0.0f, 1.0f);
            verts[iVertex+3] = D3DVertex::VertexPositionNormalTexture(x+1, 0.0f, z, n, 1.0f, g, 1.0f, 1.0f);
                }else
                if(x == X)
                if(z-1 == Z){
            verts[iVertex] = D3DVertex::VertexPositionNormalTexture(x, 0.0f, z+1, n, 1.0f, g, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            verts[iVertex+1] = D3DVertex::VertexPositionNormalTexture(x+1, 0.0f, z+1, n, 1.0f, g, 1.0f, 0.0f);
            verts[iVertex+2] = D3DVertex::VertexPositionNormalTexture(x, 0.0f, z, n, 1.0f, g, 0.0f, 1.0f);
            verts[iVertex+3] = D3DVertex::VertexPositionNormalTexture(x+1, 0.5f, z, n, 1.0f, g, 1.0f, 1.0f);
                }else
                if(x-1 == X)
                if(z == Z){
            verts[iVertex] = D3DVertex::VertexPositionNormalTexture(x, 0.5f, z+1, n, 1.0f, g, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            verts[iVertex+1] = D3DVertex::VertexPositionNormalTexture(x+1, 0.0f, z+1, n, 1.0f, g, 1.0f, 0.0f);
            verts[iVertex+2] = D3DVertex::VertexPositionNormalTexture(x, 0.0f, z, n, 1.0f, g, 0.0f, 1.0f);
            verts[iVertex+3] = D3DVertex::VertexPositionNormalTexture(x+1, 0.0f, z, n, 1.0f, g, 1.0f, 1.0f);
                }else
                if(x-1 == X)
                if(z-1 == Z){
            verts[iVertex] = D3DVertex::VertexPositionNormalTexture(x, 0.0f, z+1, n, 1.0f, g, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            verts[iVertex+1] = D3DVertex::VertexPositionNormalTexture(x+1, 0.0f, z+1, n, 1.0f, g, 1.0f, 0.0f);
            verts[iVertex+2] = D3DVertex::VertexPositionNormalTexture(x, 0.5f, z, n, 1.0f, g, 0.0f, 1.0f);
            verts[iVertex+3] = D3DVertex::VertexPositionNormalTexture(x+1, 0.0f, z, n, 1.0f, g, 1.0f, 1.0f);
                }
        indices[iIndex  ] = iVertex;
        indices[iIndex+1] = iVertex+1;
        indices[iIndex+2] = iVertex+2;
        indices[iIndex+3] = iVertex+2;
        indices[iIndex+4] = iVertex+1;
        indices[iIndex+5] = iVertex+3;

        iVertex += 4;
        iIndex += 6;
        }
    }
}
    device->CreateVertexBuffer(m_iVertexCount * sizeof(D3DVertex::VertexPositionNormalTexture),
        NULL,
        D3DVertex::VertexPositionNormalTexture::FVF,
        D3DPOOL_MANAGED,
        &vBuffer,
        NULL);

    VOID* pVerts;
    vBuffer->Lock(0, sizeof(verts), (void**)&pVerts, 0);
    memcpy_s(pVerts, sizeof(verts), verts, sizeof(verts));
    vBuffer->Unlock();
    device->CreateIndexBuffer(m_iIndeciseCount * sizeof(WORD), D3DUSAGE_WRITEONLY,
        D3DFMT_INDEX16,
        D3DPOOL_MANAGED,
        &iBuffer,
        NULL);

    VOID* pIndices;
    iBuffer->Lock(0, sizeof(indices), (void**)&pIndices, 0);
    memcpy_s(pIndices, sizeof(indices), indices, sizeof(indices));
    iBuffer->Unlock();

    //Load texture
    D3DXCreateTextureFromFile(device, texName.c_str(), &texture);
    if(!texture){
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Could not load texture", NULL, NULL);
        return;
    }
}
```

All i am asking is for a tutorial that would allow me to keep my code. And if you can help me implement an normal map and explain how that would be great but not nessasary. I want to learn directX not just copy code from another person. DIRECTX Version = June 2010

Comment: I just have to ask: Why do you use DX9 when you just start to learn graphics programming? Wouldn't a more recent version make more sense? About your question: What do you know about textures, about shaders, about lighting? If those concepts are clear to you, it should be no problem to follow any normal map tutorial without the preceeding ones. If not, those topics are probably what the preceeding tutorials are about and it is a good idea to read them. They are essential to implementing normal mapping.

Comment: Ok thank you. I followed a tutorial on youtube, i was not able to find tutorials about directX 11. But i know a normal is a way of calculating the light and a normal map renders a "shadow" on a texture, i also know about specular mapping occlusion mapping etc... but i don't know how they work. If you can give me some good reads on the subject i will surly be happy and proceed with studying the methods. Thank you.